# Use of $\operatorname{Im}, \operatorname{im}$ and $\Im$: symbologies

Tags: complex-numbers, notation, linear-transformations

When I studied maths at my University since 1993 for the linear application $f$, I have always used the operator (small letter i)
$$ \operatorname{im} f \quad \text{ or } \quad \operatorname{im} (f)$$
$$\ker f \quad \text{ or } \quad \ker(f) \quad \text{ and not } \operatorname{Ker}$$
and for complex numbers $z=a+ib$,

$$\operatorname{Im}z=b$$

even if exists the operators in $\LaTeX$, $$\Im\quad \verb|as Im z|$$ and
$$\Re\quad \verb|as Re z|$$

> Is this an universal symbology or official in all word or are there other notations?

Comment: See [Complex number: Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Notation): very few math symbols are "fully" standard... Consider e.g. *product*: $\times, \cdot, *$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Hi from the Sicily :-). I approved the notation for the complex numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ones you mentioned in your question are all the ones that I've personally come across. I find it to be perfectly clear what people mean when they use any of these notations. I do think that if you're writing any piece of mathematical literature, it can't hurt to mention the notation you're going to use throughout it.
Additionally, as Mauro Allegranza pointed out, very few symbols in maths are completely, undoubtedly standardized.
My personal preference goes to $\Re$ since it's what I've been taught.

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribute.